# Complex inequalities with fractions

Tags: complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, circles

The circle of radius $r$ in the xy-plane centred at $(a, b) \in \Bbb{R}^2$
is described by the equation $(x − a)^2 +(y − b)^2 = r^2$

> Let $z = x + iy \in \Bbb C$.
> Find the radius and the centre of the circle described on the Argand diagram given by the equation $\displaystyle \left\vert \frac{z+i}{z-1}\right\vert =2$.

I have many similar questions without fractions however i dont know what to do with the fraction should I do the division with $z=a+bi$ or not any help is apricated

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $z=x+iy$. Then you have
$$\left| \frac{x+i y+i}{x+i y-1}\right|=2$$
that is
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}=2$$
square both sides and simplify
$$3 x^2+3 y^2-8 x-2 y+3=0 \\
x^2 + y^2 -\frac8{3}x - \frac2{3}y + 1 = 0 \\
x^2 - 2 \cdot \frac4{3}x + \left(\frac4{3}\right)^2 - \left(\frac4{3}\right)^2 + y^2 - 2 \cdot \frac1{3}y + \left(\frac1{3}\right)^2 - \left(\frac1{3}\right)^2 + 1 = 0 \\
\left(x-\frac4{3}\right)^2 + \left(y - \frac1{3}\right)^2 = \frac8{9} = \left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}3\right)^2
$$

circle with center $\left(\frac43,\frac13\right)$ and radius $r=\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the equation $$\left|\dfrac{z-a}{z-b}{}\right|=c$$ where $c$ is a constant real number represents a circle known as [Apollonius Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#:%7E:text=Apollonius%20showed%20that%20a%20circle,of%20the%20Apollonius%20pursuit%20problem.). It is the locus of points whose ratio of distances from two fixed points $a$ and $b$ is a constant $c$.

[image]

Now, if we consider the question given, the two fixed points from where the distances are measured (the focii) are $A(z=-i)$ and $B(z=1)$.

The distance between the points $z=-i$ and $z=1$ is simply $\sqrt{2}$.

Therefore if we if we call the point $C$ where circle cuts the line joining $A$ and $B$, we know that $\dfrac{AC}{BC}=2$ and $AC+BC=\sqrt{2}$ so we get $AC=\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$ and $BC=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$. Now, also since $\dfrac{AD}{BD}=2$, we get $BD=\sqrt{2}$ which means diameter is $BD+BC=\sqrt{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3}=\dfrac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}.$ Hence radius is $\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$.

For coordinates of $B$, we can write the equation of the line joining them as $y=x-1$ in the $xy$ plane. So coordinates of $B$ are $\left(\dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\cos(45^{\circ}),\dfrac{-1}{3}+\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\sin(45^{\circ})\right)\equiv \left(\dfrac{4}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$